# Xamarin Forms where to change StatusBar For Android and IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and want to Navigation in all pages to have #84DCC6. It adds but i dont want to have the blue color on top (which is default in Android project )of  The navigation page, i want to have just one color #84DCC6. This is my code in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#84DCC6" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I'm testing my App on Xiaomi A2 Lite. Any suggesstions to be just one color #84DCC6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue color you are talking about is not a navigation bar, its a status bar.

**Android:**

you can change its color from Styles.xml file situated under your android project `Resource folder`:

```cs
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1eb6ed</item>
```

**iOS**

use this below code inside your app delegate class

```cs
var statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
            if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
            {
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(132, 220, 198);
                statusBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
            }
```

Comment: is this blue color showing in IOS? I dont have at the momend IOS device to test?

Comment: in iOS also you can set the color of status bar, editing my answer for the same.

Comment: By default, the UINavigationBar style in iOS is Default , which means that the letters will be black and the background color will be white.

Comment: this code add in FinishedLaunching Function in IOS?

Comment: Please find the edited answer, you can have RGB code for the same, and inside finished launching method before LoadApplication(new App()); you can place this.

Comment: Thank you MShah this code is working i marked as success !